# Load JS modules conditionally (SystemJS)

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I am currently using jspm and SystemJS to load ES6 modules. However, I would like to be able to

- Scan the page for certain selectors (e.g., `id`, `data-plugin`)
- Map these selectors to their module dependencies
- Load *only* those modules

My thought was to handle these imports through the single entry point, `System.import('src/main')`, that has access to the `document`. I could then find the relevant selectors, map those selectors to modules, and then `import` those modules.

`src/main` would look something like this:

```
['d3', 'jquery'].forEach(function(dependency) {
    import dependency;
});
```

This is not a viable solution as it is invalid syntax. Is there a better way to achieve dynamic module loading in this sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal `import` syntax can't be used to conditionally load modules, as you've already seen. To get around this, we can use the programmatic API provided by `System`. You're already familiar with this API, since you use it to `System.import('src/main');`.

To conditionally load modules, instead of using the `import` keyword, you just have to continue using the `System.import` method.

An example of this:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='one'>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>

  <script>
    System.import('main');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```
const map = {
  '#one': 'one',
  '#two': 'two'
};

for (let selector in map) {
  if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
    System.import(map[selector]);
  }
}
```

#### one.js

```
window.HAS_ONE = true;
```

#### two.js

```
window.HAS_TWO = true;
```

In this example, `window.HAS_ONE` would be defined, but `window.HAS_TWO` would remain `undefined`.

Comment: Is it possible to import a module with these mappings *before* conditionally loading the modules? e.g.:

System.import('module').then(function(m) {
  var map = m.map;
  System.import(map[selector])
});

Comment: @Himmel [Yes, that works fine.](http://plnkr.co/edit/rex9U7JUgsjCkKAzUkDi?p=preview)